# Get first unique key from map with common values

Tags: terraform

I have a deployment definition where I have a map of CIDR blocks to regions. The CIDRs of course need to be unique but the values can be repeated. In this example, I have CIDRs block going to three different regions, `us-west-1`, `us-west-2`, and `us-east-1`.

```
cidr_region_map = {
  "10.0.0.0/24" = "us-west-1", 
  "10.0.1.0/24" = "us-east-1", 
  "10.0.3.0/24" = "us-east-1",
  "10.0.4.0/24" = "us-west-1", 
  "10.0.5.0/24" = "us-west-2", 
  "10.0.6.0/24" = "us-east-1",
}
```

I need to get an array where I can pick out the first CIDR for each region from this map. This means I'd end up with a list as such:

```json
[
  "10.0.1.0/24", // us-east-1
  "10.0.0.0/24", // us-west-1
  "10.0.5.0/24", // us-west-2
]
```

Any other CIDR from a region that we've already accounted for should be ignored in this list.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for anyone to copy/paste quickly.

**playground.tf**

```
locals {
  cidr_region_map = {
    "10.0.0.0/24" = "us-west-1", 
    "10.0.1.0/24" = "us-east-1", 
    "10.0.3.0/24" = "us-east-1",
    "10.0.4.0/24" = "us-west-1", 
    "10.0.5.0/24" = "us-west-2", 
    "10.0.6.0/24" = "us-east-1",
  }

  group_by = values(
    zipmap(
      reverse(values(local.cidr_region_map)),
      reverse(keys(local.cidr_region_map))
    )
  )
}

output "test_out_2" {
  value = local.group_by
}
```

**Output**

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test_out_2 = [
  "10.0.1.0/24",
  "10.0.0.0/24",
  "10.0.5.0/24",
]
```

---

### How it Works

For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to explain how this magic works with "variables" to better visualize what's going on.

```
keys(map)   = CIDR: ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24", "10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
values(map) = VALS: ["us-west-1", "us-east-1", "us-east-1", "us-west-1", "us-west-2", "us-east-1"]
```

The way maps work in Terraform is that they can only have one key. If you try adding an existing key to the map, it'll replace the old one. For example, if you do this,

```json
{
    "us-east-1" = "10.0.3.0/24",  // this will be dropped
    "us-east-1" = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

First we want to reverse the original keys/values lists that we have so that the lower in the list it is, the less precedence it takes because then the first ones will be added later to the map so it'll overwrite the original value

```
r_CIDR = reverse(CIDR) = ["10.0.6.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.0.0/24"]
r_VALS = reverse(VALS) = ["us-east-1", "us-west-2", "us-west-1", "us-east-1", "us-east-1", "us-west-1"]
```

Now that we've reversed the values, we use `zipmap` to create a new map.

```
zipmap(r_VALS,, r_CIDR) = { 
  "us-east-1" = "10.0.6.0/24" // this will be dropped
  "us-west-2" = "10.0.5.0/24"
  "us-west-1" = "10.0.4.0/24" // this will be dropped 
  "us-east-1" = "10.0.3.0/24" // this will be dropped
  "us-east-1" = "10.0.1.0/24"
  "us-west-1" = "10.0.0.0/24"
}
```

After all those repeated keys are dropped internally, you'd be left with the following map,

```
zipmap(r_VALS,, r_CIDR) = { 
  "us-west-2" = "10.0.5.0/24"
  "us-east-1" = "10.0.1.0/24"
  "us-west-1" = "10.0.0.0/24"
}
```

Finally you take the values of that map, and you'll be left with the unique values

```
values(zipmap) = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems like it would be easier to solve with the map inverted so that the values are keys and the keys are values. We can use a `for` expression to achieve that, using the `...` modifier to activate [the grouping mode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#grouping-results) to allow for there potentially being multiple CIDR ranges for each region:

```
locals {
  cidr_region_map = {
    "10.0.0.0/24" = "us-west-1", 
    "10.0.1.0/24" = "us-east-1", 
    "10.0.3.0/24" = "us-east-1",
    "10.0.4.0/24" = "us-west-1", 
    "10.0.5.0/24" = "us-west-2", 
    "10.0.6.0/24" = "us-east-1",
  }

  region_cidr_map = {
    for cidr, region in local.cidr_region_map : region => cidr...
  }
}
```

This should produce a map of lists of strings, like this:

```
{
  us-west-1 = {
    "10.0.0.0/24",
    "10.0.4.0/24",
  }
  us-east-1 = {
    "10.0.1.0/24",
    "10.0.3.0/24",
    "10.0.6.0/24",
  }
  us-west-2 = {
    "10.0.6.0/24",
  }
}
```

Because the for expression will only include a key if there's at least one value for that key, we can assume that all of the lists will have at least one element, and so to take the first one we can just access it as normal with the `[0]` [indexing syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#indices-and-attributes):

```
locals {
  region_first_cidr_map = {
    for region, cidrs in local.region_cidr_map : region => cidrs[0]
  }
}
```

That should then produce the following, which I think matches your requirement:

```
{
  us-west-1 = "10.0.0.0/24"
  us-east-1 = "10.0.1.0/24"
  us-west-2 = "10.0.6.0/24"
}
```

(You can use `values` on this map if you only want the CIDR blocks themselves and don't care about which region each belongs to.)

Note that which CIDR block it chooses from each region will be decided by Terraform's traversal order for maps in `for` expressions, which is in lexical order by key. Since the original map had CIDR blocks as keys, it's the lexical ordering of the CIDR blocks that will decide the order, and that happens to match the intuitive numeric ordering with this example where each address has the same number of digits, but that wouldn't be true if you had e.g. `10.0.10.0/24` and `10.0.2.0/24`, because `10.0.10.0/24` is lexically "before" `10.0.2.0/24`, even though that isn't true numerically.